# Flutter: Problem in timer for quiz app to navigate next question

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I created flutter android app for quiz application
[quiz_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w54ET.png)
questions and answers and time of questions are saved in map like this:

```
static List<int> quesIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  static Map<int, String> ques = {
    1: "question 1",
    2: "question 2",
    3: "question 3",
    4: "question 4",
    5: "question 5",
  };
  static Map<int, String> times = {1: "30", 2: "20", 3: "60", 4: "40", 5: "30"};
  static Map<int, Map<int, String>> ans = {
    1: {1: "ans1-1", 2: "ans1-2", 3: "ans1-3"},
    2: {4: "ans2-1", 5: "ans2-2", 6: "ans2-3"},
    3: {7: "ans3-1", 8: "ans3-2", 9: "ans3-3"},
    4: {10: "ans4-1", 11: "ans4-2", 12: "ans4-3"},
    5: {13: "ans5-1", 14: "ans5-2", 15: "ans5-3"},
  };
```

I want timer method to start count down when the question shows and navigate to next question when timer finish, but when user click next button before time finish, the timer stops and navigate next question with new timer countdown of next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a timer function when your counter value reaches your desired time change the question and reset the counter value

```
  int _counter = 10;
  Timer _timer;

 void _startTimer() {
_counter = 10;
if (_timer != null) {
  _timer.cancel();
}
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    if (_counter > 0) {
      _counter--;
    } else {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
  });
});
}
```